# Define class in Typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm writing a Typescript module for an external library.

Here's a piece of my `index.d.ts`

```ts
declare module 'my-external-library' {
  export class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps> {}

  export class CustomClass {
    constructor(
     firstParam: string,
     secondParam: string,
    )
  }

  interface MyComponentProps {
    config: string
    customClass: CustomClass
    text?: string
    customFn?: (input: string) => boolean
  }

}
```

This works fine except for the `customClass` prop.
Custom Class is a class that has to be like this:

```ts
class customClass {
  constructor(firstParam, secondParam) {
    this.firstParam = firstParam
    this.secondParam = secondParam
  }

  ... all the methods you want
}

export default customClass
```

In a separate file I give the `customClass` props to `MyComponent`, like this:

```ts
import customClass from './customClass'

<MyComponent
    config: "test"
    customClass: customClass
/>
```

`customClass` actually is not receiving the "constructor types" declared in `index.d.ts`, but all other props of the component works well.
So, the class definition I've made is correct? I have to export the class with another approach?

Here's a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-nrfk2

Thanks for any help, forgive my inexperience

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly, but maybe you're wanting to extend CustomClass? Otherwise the customClass implementation has no relationship to the CustomClass type definition?

class customClass extends CustomClass {
    ...
}

Comment: Might be just an error in the question, but your type definition is for `CustomClass` while your js code is for `customClass` (JavaScript **IS** case sensitive)

Comment: @RobertDempsey I understand what you're saying. My thought is that the relationship exist because I give the props "customClass" to the component `MyComponent`. The type check works fine for the other props, why not with the class? Is it mandatory to extends the class so that inherit the type?

Comment: @AramBecker No, my tipe definiton is for customClass props. The type name makes no difference. I also tried to be sure

Comment: I think I'd need to see some more code to help you with the question. Are you able to provide a StackBlitz or a Typescript Playground URL? There might be some assumed knowledge about React here, but it'd be good to see a bare minimum reproduction of the issue if possible.

Comment: @RobertDempsey many thanks for your time, I very appreciate it. I updated the question with a link to a playground. I also add some comments in the code that I hope will help to explain my problem. I apologize for the app not working in the playground, but no matter. The type check works  and that's the point.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to set this up. I'm afraid I still don't quite understand the question. Specfically, I'm looking at `ActionProvider.ts`. This _is_ where you are defining the ActionProvider class, and there is no link between ActionProvider and your `index.d.ts` file, so it cannot inherit something you are not referencing at all. 

If you want your class to infer the types of its variables, you'll need to either do `class ActionProvider extends SomeOtherClass` or `class ActionProvider implements SomeInterface`

Comment: I was thinking the link is that I give `ActionProvider` class to the props of Chatbot Component. The types of the props of Chatbot are defined in `index.d.ts` like happens in the config object. But it's not enough... I must proceed in the two ways you are quoted

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `customClass: typeof CustomClass` in the MyComponentProps definition? If you want to pass the class itself as a value then the type needs to be the type of the constructor not the type of the instance.

Answer (score 4):

I've forked and edited your code sandbox, check it out:

[image: Edit React Typescript Playground (forked)]

Now I'm gonna explain a few things about class in typescript, which is indeed quite confusing.

It's in part due to the fact that people use the term "class" to refer to diff things in diff contexts. To disambiguate, let's use more accurate terms.

##### Constructor

`MyPuppy` is often called a "class", but it's also a "constructor function" in JS terms. So let's stick to **constructor** throughout this discussion.

```js
// javascript
class MyPuppy {}
```

##### Instance

Variable `puppy` is an **instance** of `MyPuppet`

```js
// javascript
const puppy = new MyPuppet()
```

##### Instance Type vs Constructor Type

In typescript, when you declare a class like below, you'll *implicitly* declare an **instance type** of the same name!

This behaviour confuses a lot of people. In short, `MyPuppy` as a *JS variable* holds a **constructor**, whereas `MyPuppy` as a *TS type variable* actually holds an **instance type**.

Now how do we refer to the type of `MyPuppy` constructor, aka the **constructor type**? You should literally use `typeof MyPuppy`.

```
// typescript
class MyPuppet {}

type MyPuppetInstance = MyPuppet
type MyPuppetConstructor = typeof MyPuppet
```

---

We've done disambiguating terms, let's do some case study.

There's this concept of the "instance side" and "static side" of a class, once documented in the [old TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes). Basically "instance side" corresponds to **instance type**, "static side" to **constructor type**.

```
class MyPuppy {
  static getSpecies(dog: MyPuppy) {
    return dog.species
  }

  constructor(species: string) { this.species = species }

  species: string

  // [side note] above two lines can be combined as one:
  // constructor(public species: string) {}

  poop() { return '' }
}

type MyPuppetInstance = MyPuppet
type MyPuppetConstructor = typeof MyPuppet


var bar: MyPuppetConstructor = MyPuppy
var foo: MyPuppetInstance = new bar("shiba_inu")
```

The above snippet does several things.

1. Declare a JS **constructor** of the name `MyPuppy`.
2. Implicitly declare a TS **instance type** `MyPuppy`.
3. On the "instance side", `foo` is an **instance**, and has a property `species` and a method `poop`.
4. On the "static side", the `bar` is a **constructor**, it's a "newable function" which can be invoked as `new bar("shiba_inu")`, and also has a static method `getSpecies`.

Now in a `.d.ts` file, how can we declare the above types? You can use either the `interface` keyword or the `type` keyword. They make almost no difference.

```
// index.d.ts

interface MyPuppyInstance {
  species: string
  poop(): string
}

interface MyPuppyConstructor {
  new (species: string): MyPuppyInstance
  getSpecies(dog: { species: string }): string
}

type MyPuppyInstance2 = {
  species: string
  poop(): string
}

type MyPuppyConstructor2 = 
  (new (species: string) => MyPuppyInstance)
  & { getSpecies(dog: { species: string }): string }
```